# Trouble connecting ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, mapping

I have a very simple web application, where I try to let people register a user. Therefore, I try to save user-registration data to Entity Framework, but with no luck.

I have a basic model and a basic view, so for the sake of brevity I am not going to post them as of right now, as I don't think the problem lies within them. If anybody would like to see them, I will post them. I am trying to make use of **app.UseAuthentication** and my guess is that some of my logic is wrong. I am trying to save to the table **dbo.AspNetUsers**.

**Startup.cs**

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                            .AddJsonFile(env.ContentRootPath + "/appsettings.json")
                            .Build();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(options =>           
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>()
                                        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}");
        });

        app.UseFileServer();   
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyLocalDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new CombinedLoginAndRegisterModel());
    }

    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    //Registration
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser(CombinedLoginAndRegisterModel cbr)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            Email = cbr.Register.Email
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, cbr.Register.Password); //wait

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Data Context**

```
public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public IdentityDataContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help greatly and will respond to requests/comments.

**EDIT**

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model CS_config.Models.CombinedLoginAndRegisterModel

<h2>Register account</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Register.Email, new { style = "margin-right: 7px;" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Email)<br><br>

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Register.Password, new { style = "margin-right: 10px;" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Register.Password)<br><br>

    <button type="submit" name="RegisterUser">Submit</button> //named it to match the Task `RegisterUser` in the Controller
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @Drewskis No, not any that I am aware of that is. When I submit my basic form, the View also returns correctly. However, the table dbo.AspNetUsers remains empty. There might be error messages with entity framework/behind the scene, that I am not aware of, but not sure how to check that if that would be the case.

Comment: When you debug, what shows in your console when you add a watch to result?

Comment: This link may also be of some use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Drewskis Interesting, thanks for the advice. I added a watch to `result`, tried to submit the form in debug mode and nothing happened. So apparently, the async task `RegisterUser` is not triggered when I try to submit... The button is included in my form though and type property on it is set to submit.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your cshtml page. If you're not hitting a breakpoint when debugging after clicking submit then something is most likely wrong there.

Comment: @Drewskis I added it at the bottom of the post. I have to forms in my view, but only included the relevant - just to be sure I tried to submit the other form, but without results also. Maybe I didn't map the form properly to match the Task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183374/discussion-between-drewskis-and-thesystem).

Comment: @Drewskis Hey man, I think I figured out the problem - I am now able to get to the method/hit breakpoints! Im fairly confident that the problem was this: my form took two input fields, one for Email and one for Password. When I click on submit button, it tries to submit these two fields.

However, my Controller-action `RegisterUser` didn't take these as parameters. First, it took CombinedLoginAndRegisterModel, and later it took only `string Email`, but never `string Password` as well, so it wasnt able to map the Action.

Thank you for all the help you put in a couple days ago though! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually found out a bunch of problems and why it didn't work. One thing I hadn't done was to do an initial migration and/or updated database with `Add-Migration [name]` and `Update-Database`

Most of my other problems are further explained in here: [Controller Action not triggered - Simple Project - ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264932/controller-action-not-triggered-simple-project-asp-net-mvc-core-2-0) - also check the comments to both this post and the linked post

If anybody has same problems, feel free to write me.