# Controller Action not triggered - Simple Project - ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, identity

I have a very simple web application, where I try to let people register a user. Therefore, I try to save user-registration data to Entity Framework, but with no luck.

For some reason, IActionResult `RegisterUser` isn't triggered when submitting a form (I tried setting breakpoints, nothing happened). Can anyone detect why?

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=APIExercise2;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}");
        });
        app.UseFileServer();
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model CS_ConfigSettings.Models.Register

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="RegisterUser" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Email" type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser(Register register)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            Email = register.Email
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);

        return View();

    }
}
```

**Register.cs**

```
public class Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Register> register { get; set; }
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, the breakpoints set in Controller-action `RegisterUser` aren't triggered, and the Database-table `register` isn't updated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use Chrome Developer Tools or Fiddler to confirm that to post is being sent to your controller?

Comment: @KevinRaffay When I click on button to submit, it reponds with Status Code 200 and the Request Method is POST. It just doesn't seem to trigger my method in the Controller class.

Comment: @KevinRaffay I believe I found the problem. My form in the view has two input fields, Email and Password, that I try to submit. However, my ActionResult doesn't match to take in those parameters, hence it was never triggered. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Good catch, not sure why it did not bind the fields to the Register model.

Comment: @KevinRaffay Just a follow up, if you are curious; seems the reason why my fields didn't bind to the model was because I hadn't added tag-helpers to my view. This line in the top of my view seems to have done the job: `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you do realize that Identity creates tables for you?  They are usually named AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetRoleUsers, etc... so creating `register` will be a table that Identity will never use.

If those tables listed previously aren't in your database created then you need to create a migration, usually your `initial` migration which creates all of the Identity Tables.  either using the PMC commands or command line with `dotnet`.  I suggest that you re-create the project with Individual users accounts selected to scaffold Identity features for you.

The fact that you haven't been able to hit that method with a break point... For one that UseFileServer is interfering with MVC... always always have `UseMVC()` be the last entry.  Order does matter.

As soon as that method does get hit it will error out since UserManager will die due the tables not existing since that will be location of the new created user in `AspNetUsers`

commandline:  `dotnet ef migrations add <nameofmigration>`

PMC: `Add-Migration <nameofmigration>`

then run `Update-Database` this will commit all the changes you just made.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

### Code Fragment from one of my projects

```
 //remainder of Startup.cs left out for brevity    
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();

        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

       
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            
        });
```

Comment: Hey, your comment greatly helped me solve the problems I had. I didn't know that `Identity` wouldn't work with a custom table, but only its own. Since default Identity tables were missing, this lead me to spot error in my **DataContext.cs** class: the class inherited from `DbContext`, but it should be `IdentityDbContext`. Finally, for some reason, in Controller-method `RegisterUser`, `user` had to be instantiated with a username additionally to `Email` (dont know why?) - so thanks for helping me in the right direction! If anyone has this problem in the future, dont hesitate to write me